# One IP, Two Virtual Hosts

Tags: apache2, dns

I have two sites with DNS pointing at a single IP and two corresponding xxx.conf files in Apache2. When I enter either host's domain name from an external browser Apache always returns the first domain's site. When checking the HTTP Request header using WireShark the host entry is always shown as my IP address, rather than the corresponding domain that I had entered in the external browser. I am using a port 80 to 8080 redirect through a managed DNS service. When my IP is shown as the host in the HTTP header it has :8080 attached but no domain to show Apache which site to serve. Anyone?

Thanks,
Elwood

Comment: Please post the content of both conf files.

Comment: <VirtualHost *:8080>

 DocumentRoot /var/www/www.aaa.com/public_html

 ServerName www.aaa.com
 ServerAlias aaa.com

 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

Comment: <VirtualHost *:8080>
 
 DocumentRoot /var/www/www.bbb.com/public_html

 ServerName www.bbb.com
 ServerAlias bbb.com

 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>